# How can I fix phpMyAdmin, broken after Ubuntu update?

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I updated Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.04 and during the update process it asked for my dba password so it could update phpMyAdmin, however it kept refusing it. Possibly due to it saying it was trying root@localhost when I believe the username may be admin instead? I may be wrong. Anyway, the update completed. Now the /phpmyadmin page no longer has the .htaccess protection and is just blank?

I'm running WordPress and everything else seems to be okay, but I just want to be able to fix, and update phpMyAdmin so it's back to normal again! I've been playing with Ubuntu for a few years, but am still a beginner with this!

How can I fix this?

Comment: First remove phpmyadmin using `sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin`  and reinstall it again see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove PHPMyAdmin

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

Reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```